# Find amount of a certain element in JSON (Python)

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

My code currently pulls WHOIS data and prints certain information about a URL, such as registrar and domain name. For example for google.com, the domain names are "GOOGLE.COM" and "google.com". Some websites will have more or less, how would I go about finding the number of data points in a JSON element. For example 124.com, 123.net, and 123.org would print 3.

Comment: Think about a function that returns the "interesting part" of the item. E.g. for "GOOGLE.COM" and "google.com" it could return "google", and for "123.com", "123.net" and "123.org" it could return "123".

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have enough reputation to comment and ask for clarification yet)

I don't know what your WHOIS JSON object looks like, but maybe this will help:

```py
whois={'Company XYZ': {'domain_names':['124.com', '124.net', '124.org']}}
print(len(whois['Company XYZ']['domain_names']))
```

will output `3`.